# Onenote API create page

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create new pages through the OneNote API. I'm following [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/tutorials/node) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0).

It seems like header() is not working.

**graph-tutorial\graph.js:**

```
createPage: async function(sectionID, content, accessToken) {
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

  console.log('DEBUG:', '[Creating Pages]', sectionID);
  const res = await client
    .api(`/me/onenote/sections/${sectionID}/pages`)
    .header({
      'Content-type': 'application/xhtml+xml'
    })
    .post(content);

  return res;
}
```

**route\onenote.js:**

```
let content = 
        `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>${subject}</title>
            <meta name="created" content="${creationDate}" />
          </head>
          <body>
            ${description}
          </body>
        </html>`

        let page = await graph.createPage(section.id, content, accessToken);
```

**Error:**

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  code: 'BadRequest',
  message: 'Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.'
  .... }
```

Comment: worked with: `.header('Content-type', 'application/xhtml+xml')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header` method takes two string parameters ("Key" and "Value"). From the [SDK sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/7529db87dc076514a44f94378152ba31f654ad61/samples/node/main.js):

```
client
    .api('/me')
    .header("content-type", "application/json")
    .update({
        "birthday": "1908-12-22T00:00:00Z"
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("Updated my birthday");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

In your case, you want:

```
const res = await client
  .api(`/me/onenote/sections/${sectionID}/pages`)
  .header('Content-type', 'application/xhtml+xml')
  .post(content);
```

Comment: Thanks. I should use `headers(headers:  { [key: string]: string | number; }): this;` or `header(headerKey: string, headerValue: string): this;`

Answer (score -1):

Content-type should be **Content-Type** with a capital 'T' in Type.

Comment: didn't work. `.header({'Content-Type':'application/xhtml+xml'})`